# MIPS - Frequency of EACH lowercase, uppercase, and space characters

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips, frequency

I am trying to count the number of times a character appears, both upper and lower case along with space characters from an inputted string from the keyboard.

I understand that in ASCII, a-z is 97 - 122, and A-Z is 65-90. I'm not sure how to implement this algorithm in assembly as I am very new with it and the concept confuses me.

My psuedocode is something along the lines of:

```
// Uppercase
array[0] = -65
if (character read from string > 64) {
   if (character read from string < 91) {
     increment array[i] based on character
   }
}
// Print out integers stored in array (the frequency)
```

I am not sure if that is the way to approach the problem.

```
    .data
prompt:     .asciiz "Please enter a string: \n"
userString: .space 104
occLow:     .space 104
occUpp:     .space 104
newLine:    .asciiz "\n"

#######################
# t0 = string
# t1 = char being looked at
# t2 = counter
# s0 = array lower (occLow)
# s1 = array upper (occUpp)
#######################

    .text
main:   li $v0, 4
        la $a0, prompt       # Prompts the user for string
        syscall

        li $v0, 8            # Save string to $a0
        la $a0, userString
        move $t0, $a0         # Move $a0 to $t0
        syscall

test:   lb $t1, 0($t0)         # Load each individual character
        beqz $t1, end           # If it is null, end program
        addi $t0, $t0, 1         # Next char

        beq $t1, 32, space      # If the character is a space
        blt $t1, 91, upper      # Uppercase character, 90 = 'Z'
        bgt $t1, 96, lower      # Lowercase character
        b test


upper1: bgt $t1, 64, upper2 # 65 = 'A'
        b test
upper2: # UPPERCASE ADDITIONS HERE
        # la $s0, occUpp
        # add $t0, $t0, 4
        # lw $t1, 0($s0)
        # addi $t2, 1
        # sw $t1,
```

Comment: Your pseudo code is too pseudo. Write a working implementation in C using only: 1) `goto`  2) only single assignment (e.g. no `y = 2*x+z`)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // Uppercase
> array[0] = -65
> if (character read from string > 64) {
>    if (character read from string < 91) {
>      increment array[i] based on character
>    }
> }
> // Print out integers stored in array (the frequency)
> ```

Some annoying style notes:

---

Why > 64 and < 91 when you wrote uppercase are 65 to 90? Actually most of the assemblers can handle the ASCII form, so uppercase is then from `'A'` to `'Z'`.

In pseudo code I would try to keep true to my original intention, so checking if character is from `65` to `90` (inclusive).

```
character = next_char();
if (character < 'A') goto not_uppercase;
if ('Z' < character) goto not_uppercase;
// uppercase detected
...

not_uppercase:
// character is not uppercase
...
```

---

*"increment array[i] based on character"*

So you want `i` based on character. What is character? Some value from 0 to 255, as you the input is ASCII encoded, so single character is 8 bit value. Is value 0-255 good enough for indexing array? Actually it is, if you reserve 256 element array. You can be more memory efficient by checking for codes you don't need to count statistics for, like counting stats only for values 32-127, then you would need only array of 96 counters, and index would be `(character-32)`. Or even uppercasing lower case letters by `-32` (`'a'-32 == 'A'` <=> `97-32 == 65`), if you want to count lowercase letters together with uppercase letters.

But you can as well use 256 element array to count them all individually (even non-printable content of string), and then pick/group only uppercase/lowercase/whitespace/digits parts of it, as you wish.

So then pseudocode may look like this:

```
charCounters = array(256) { 0, 0, ... };
// ^^^ counters for each possible letter set to zero
for_each(character in string) {
    ++charCounters[character];   // count particular letter
}
// counters are now updated, displaying results

// for example total count of uppercase
uppercaseLettersTotalCount = 0;
for (i = 'A' to 'Z') {
    uppercaseLettersTotalCount += charCounters[i];
}
display("Total uppercase letters: " + uppercaseLettersTotalCount);

// number of 'A' letters, both upper and lowercase
totalA = charCounters['A'];
totalA += charCounters['a'];
display("Total A/a letters: " + totalA);

// ... etc
```

---

If you want just to display counts of individual characters from a short string (5-30 letters), it will be faster and less memory intensive to do naive destructive two inner loops, going through the string char by char and counting the same characters from the remaining part of string:

```
for (string_index in [0, string_length - 1]) {
    character = string[string_index];
    if (0 == character) continue;   // was already counted
    count = 1;
    for (index2 in [string_index + 1, string_length - 1]) {
        if (character != string[index2]) continue;  // different char
        ++count;              // same character found
        string[index2] = 0;   // mark as counted (destroys input string)
    }
    display("Character " + character + " found " + count + " many times.\n");
}
```